# rails relationships, 3 levels at least

Tags: ruby-on-rails, relationships

How can i authentically use rails relationships in my case?

I'm making a nightlife website, just for you to know the context. It has three models, i want to join on one page: Places, Albums, Photos.

So, `photos` in `albums` work great, i use there a custom-coded sql with joins.
But when i click on a `place` i want to see info from `place` model and a list of `albums` with a sample `photo` (first for example)

Now i have the following:

```
class Place < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :albums
end

class Album < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :photos
  has_one :place
end

class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :album
end
```

And there how i get it in my controller:

```
@place = Place.find( params[:id], :include => :albums )
```

and i get @place.albums as an object with albums data. But i don`t know how to dig even deeper to reach the`photos`model. And anywhay i can`:include => :albums`because i have no direct relations between`place`and`album`, but i have them in`album > photo` so sql join is needed?

That's a complicated question, but i just don`t get it fully.

Thank you for any help, maybe a good link to read!

Comment: Are you sure you have `has_one :place` in your `Album` model? It should be `belongs_to :place` as per Rails documentation: "The belongs_to association is always used in the model that has the foreign key".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the association between Place and Album isn't correct. The way you have it setup, it looks like neither would have a foreign_key. In other words, it should be `Album belongs_to :place`, with `place_id` in the `albums` table.

Second of all, to get the first photo for each album:

```
<% @place.albums.each do |album| %>
  Sample Photo: <%= image_tag(album.photos.first.url) %>
<% end %>
```

If you really wanted to, you could get the first photo from the first album of a place in one line:

```
<%= image_tag(@place.albums.first.photos.first.url) %>
```

First note that this is prone to nil errors if you don't add in conditionals, so I don't actually recommend this method. But, if you were to use it, I would just add a method to the Place model:

```
def first_photo
  albums.first.photos.first
end
```

And in your view:

```
<%= image_tag(@place.first_photo.url) %>
```

You'll want to join this stuff together as well so you're not performing too many queries. Wizard of Ogz answer covers that.

Comment: +1 good catch with the relation problem.  I think I misinterpreted the question to only relate to nested includes

Comment: That's very nice, i think i've almost got it =) And it works!

Answer (score 1):

There is a hash syntax for nested includes.  It also works for joins.

```
@place = Place.find( params[:id], :include => {:albums => :photos} )
```

Here is the documentation for this http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html
Look under the heading "Eager loading of associations"

Comment: Be careful when using eager loading.  If you have a lot of albums or photos they can take up a lot of memory and slow down your response times.

Comment: Thank you too, now i just know what to use, after everything works. I typed `:joins` instead of `:include` and it works just the same, but as far as i know joins perform better, than different selects with `in()` statement